# Visualization of cryptography

Tags: encryption, aes, prime-numbers

I think [CrypTool](http://www.cryptool.org/en/) is great software. And what I find most useful in it is visualization of algorithms such as Caesar, Vigenere, AES, DES. And my question is: does anyone know other tools which are intended for visual explanation of basic cryptography and related topics such as prime numbers, elliptic curves, finite fields, factorization etc? I am looking for short videos, games, animation, comics, presentations, popular science films. I am lecturer at University, and my goal is to awake students' interest in cryptography and convince them that it's one of the most exciting disciplines. What would you recommend me?

Answer (score 5):

Check out the videos from [Art of Problem](https://www.youtube.com/user/ArtOfTheProblem)  there are some amazing videos on [cryptography](https://www.youtube.com/course?list=ECB4D701646DAF0817). Short and good visual ones they nail the point, am sure you would love them.